# Django unique_together constraint for date validation

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

I have following model:

```
class Completion(models.Model):
    date_completed = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    related_task = models.ForeignKey(Task, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I need to check that each `Completion` have unique date (not datetime - only the date) for each Task (which is `Completion`'s related field). In other words, I need something like this:

```
class Meta:
    unique_together = [
        'date_completed__date',
        'related_task'
    ]
```

I know it does not work this way (and should not), so I would like to ask, how can I achieve the desired result (if it is possible altogether).

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to add a new attribute to hold just a DateField and use it for the constraint. I recognize that doesn't do exactly what you ask, and would require allowing nulls first, converting current datetime values for the date only field but depending where you are with this process it may be feasible. As I understand, the uniqueness is enforced at the database level and a function to strip off the time probably isn't going to work.

In the [unique_together](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/options/#unique-together) section

> the appropriate UNIQUE statements are included in the CREATE TABLE
> statement

As a side note, the documentation suggests using [UniqueConstraint](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/constraints/#uniqueconstraint) as

> Use UniqueConstraint with the constraints option instead.
>
> UniqueConstraint provides more functionality than unique_together.
> unique_together may be deprecated in the future.

Comment: I really wouldn't want to do this. The reason I am asking how to validate input in meta is because I am just trying to figure out how to do it correctly (I assume this is the right way to do it). I could just write a function that validates incoming data from the client before inserting it into the database if I needed some working but not very efficient solution, but my intuition tells me that this should be the preferred way.

Comment: I think the difference is the unique_together enforces with database level constraints which can be a good thing in some circumstances. Validation can occur in the model's save method, a field's validators argument, or in a forms validation. It's a question of whether you are enforcing data integrity or performing data validation. The efficiency is up to how it is written in the validator. If not adding a new field, I'd pick between the save method or field validator.

Comment: Thank you for help! Overriding the .save() method seems suits me.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [unique_for_date](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#unique-for-date) property in the field options according to the documentation. For anyone struggling with the same problem, it might worth checking it out. For your example, it would look like this:

```
class Completion(models.Model):
    date_completed = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    related_task = models.ForeignKey(Task, unique_for_date='date_completed', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

If you have multiple constraints, this might not be the best option though.

Answer (score -1):

You can use database functions in unique constraints, doing something like this to truncate to a certain date.

```
class Meta:
    constraints = [
        models.UniqueConstraint(TruncDate('date'), 'habit', name="habit_date_unique"),
    ]
```

[Using `unique_for_date` will only perform validation django-level, not at db level, so it's not as safe.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45003692/7385566)